# Item Update "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: 2010, powershell, loop

If I run each line individually, it works.  But If I try to run the script with the for each loop, I get:
Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Code:

```
 $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
   $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

 foreach($item in $listItems)
       {  
             # DeleteItems
             # UpdateItems
             # CancelWorkflows
             $reason = $item["Reason"] + "  -- This Exception was open more than 30 days and will be closed by the administrator"
             $item["Reason"] = $reason
             $item.Update()
             Write-Host "Added Reason Code - $($item.ID)"
              $reason = $null
              $count = $count+1
       }
```

Do I need to update a different way?
When I break and check the variables, $item["Reason"] is empty so it makes sense that I have 0 arguments.

More Info:  There are some columns that are required.  There is a chance one of them may be empty and so the item can't be updated unless that field has a value.  Can I force an update to an item even if a required field is blank?

Comment: 1. Updating an item _by code_ with some required field missing is not a problem. 2. `$reason` being empty is not what's mentionned by the error message, that simply states the error occurs on `Update()` (aka _"Update" with "0" argument(s)_). So the truth is elsewhere...

Comment: So how can I ensure there is an argument to update?  If I break the code and ask what is in $item.["Reason"] it is empty. I thought that is that the error meant, "there is nothing to update"

Answer (score 0):

OK, following my comment above, I had another thought for the problem. It's probably your new `$reason` value being longer than 255 characters. If your `Reason` field is a single-line text field, it cannot contain a string >255 char, hence the error message.

Comment: It is a Notes type field, rich text multiline, but I appreciate the insight.

Comment: rich text multiline means it expects some HTML-formatted text. Maybe there's something wrong in your text, like a character-sequence forbidden in HTML? I'd dump the value of `$reason` right before calling `Update`: I'd bet you'd find something in the last `$reason` printed out right before the error is raised.